# spark-cassnadra connector issue

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark 1.6.2 with scala version 2.10.5.[image]

Now I have installed cassndra locally and downloaded spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.6.2.jar from  https://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

But when I am trying to fire up the spark shell from the cassandra using the connector I am getting this error
[image]

can some one please help me if I am downloading the wrong version of the connector or there are some other issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just put `:` between `spark-cassandra-connector` and `1.6.2` instead of `_`, and remove the `;` character after the version of connector...

```
spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.2-s_2.10
```

But it's better to use latest from 1.6.x release: 1.6.11 instead of 1.6.2